# Why is it not possible to switch SQL mode on MySQL 8 running on Mac?

Tags: mysql

I am getting an error in MySQL 8 (local install) running the same queries as on MySQL 5.7 (production) regarding SQL mode. Trying to switch the SQL mode results in restart errors of MySQL. Version: 8.0.23 on OSX 11.2.3 runing on Intel

SQL error:

```
vl=eror msg="query error" logger=tsdb.mysql err="Error 1055: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.a.END_TIME' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"
```

Chaning mode a[s described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by)
My.cnf

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Restart failes.
MySQL erorror log:

```
2021-03-27T10:51:58.916408Z 0 [Note] [MY-010120] [Server] Binlog end
2021-03-27T10:52:09.208939Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Error while setting value 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' to 'sql_mode'.
2021-03-27T10:52:09.209219Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You **MUST** have `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in your sql_mode - otherwise, your queries will produce erroneous results! Do not remove it for any reason IMHO! Don't be tempted by the "easy fix" of taking it out, just to get "results" - results with errors are worse than useless!

Comment: See [this SO answer on why you should keep it enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824498/why-should-not-disable-only-full-group-by/64831540#64831540)

Answer (score 0):

It produces error, because sql_mode `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` was removed from MySQL 8.0, so it will refuse to start if you include it in the list.